# goToByIdAsync method of Office JS API not working correctly with Excel online

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-online

I am developing an add-in using the Office JS API. I am using **goToByIdAsync** method for navigate to the cell. This method works fine with the Excel Desktop but when I try to use it in Excel online navigation does not work and my worksheet(which I passed as a reference to the goToByIdAsync method) becomes blank.

**Office.context.document.goToByIdAsync("Sheet1!A2", Office.GoToType.NamedItem);**